# Ubuntu 18 set max cpu frequence

Tags: kernel, cpufreq

I'm trying to lower my cpu max frequency. I'm using a laptop which easily overheat. I've tried a number of different things but couldnt get it to work as intended. From what I can see, my cpu max frequencies are set to 2.4 GHz, but they often exceed that and reach 3.4 GHz (turbo).

- ubuntu 18
- kernel: 4.15.0-58-generic
- Scaling governor: ondemand
- Scaling driver: acpi-cpufreq

**Solved**

As Doug Smythies posted in the comments.
First read this file to see what cpu frequencies are available:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

I want to set 2400000Hz (2.4GHz) as my max cpu frequency. I believe the
 same frequency must be set on all CPU's.

```
for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq; do echo "2400000" > $file; done
```

(This action requires root privileges).
The effect should take place immediately.

Comment: the answer depends on your processor. Please edit your question with what CPU frequency scaling driver and governor you are using. Do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and add the results to you question. see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666351/how-to-scale-intel-pstate-driver-on-ubuntu-15-04/666491#666491)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587978/can-i-upper-limit-the-cpu-frequency/587983#587983) should work for you.

Comment: You can set governor to performance like this `sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 0 --governor performance` - do this command for every core that Your CPU has. This one command sets governor only for core 0.

Comment: @DougSmythies I can set my frequency (to some of the scaling_available_frequencies). However, everytime I reboot my settings are lost.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you really just want to disable turbo frequencies. If so, I would do that in the BIOS, and then it will persist through re-boots. Another alternative is to run a thermal monitoring daemon, like thermald, to limit the processor temperature.

Comment: Use TLP and use it in bat mode while on AC.